# Jenkins : Cannot invoke method scheduleBuild() on null object

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using System Groovy script in Jenkins to invoke another job.
Below is my code :

```
def trigger(BRANCH)
{
println "$BRANCH"
println "pppppp"

// Start another job
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('Step2')
def anotherBuild
try {
    def params = [
      new StringParameterValue('BRANCH', BRANCH),
    ]
    def future = job.scheduleBuild(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction(params))
    println "Waiting for the completion of " + HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + job.url, job.fullDisplayName)
    anotherBuild = future.get()
} catch (CancellationException x) {
    throw new AbortException("${job.fullDisplayName} aborted.")
}
println HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + anotherBuild.url, anotherBuild.fullDisplayName) + " completed. Result was " + anotherBuild.result

// Check that it succeeded
build.result = anotherBuild.result
if (anotherBuild.result != Result.SUCCESS && anotherBuild.result != Result.UNSTABLE) {
    // We abort this build right here and now.
    throw new AbortException("${anotherBuild.fullDisplayName} failed.")
}
}
```

I am unable to trigger the new job while executing this code.The new job takes 1 parameter "BRANCH". I have taken reference of this code from https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

But I am getting the error :

```
pppppp
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method scheduleBuild() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
```

Comment: This line `def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('Step2')` seems to be returning null. Are you sure there is a job called `Step2`

Comment: Yes. This is resolved.It was returning null.